# How can I find the source of a css style loaded by customize.php in my Wordpress blog?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to alter the layout of my blog, specifically the *Navigation Bar*, but some pre configured css style is loaded by **customize.php**. Sometimes it's **load-style.php**, and both have an extended parameter (I know nothing about it), like customize.php?url=https...blhablahblah.

How do I find the source of these css codes?

I could make some changes by adding new codes to the **style.css** and **style.min.css**, and also to the custom css area provided by the Generate Press Theme, but it would be easier if I could delete or alter some lines from this mysterious source.
(by the way, all I know of coding I learned in the past 3 days, trying to set my blog online. I had great intuitions from the Chrome developer tools).

Here's what I get from inspecting with the Chrome DevTools:

```
.main-navigation .main-nav ul li[class*="current-menu-"] > a {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

That is part of a style loaded by the php files, and it's shown as one single long line in the source code inspection.

When I open the php files, I don't find these lines, so I suppose they load it from another source, and I still can't understand the php language.

I wish I could alter it, or at least delete or disable it, because this line has other style I don't want loaded.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't modify core files of WordPress because your changes may affect something else or be wiped out with each version release.

What you can do is in your style.css just at the !important to your CSS to override it.

For example:

```
.main-navigation .main-nav ul li[class*="current-menu-"] > a {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly!

I was only trying to change in the source because I wanted to keep those codes as clean as possible, and not pile up a bunch of new codes there. There are still some things, like a **focus** code going on when I hover over the current-menu, but it's not that annoying...

Thank you a lot for helping me!

Comment: Why would you suggest he duplicate CSS code and use the `!important` directive instead of suggesting that he use a child theme which would a.) allow him to override the code cleanly and b.) provide him with the flexibility to modify additional template files without losing his changes when there is an update

Comment: Mainly because he is not fluent in Php and to do as you suggest would require a modicum of PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code its hard to suggest the solution. However, I guess, your theme is using inline style function **wp_add_inline_style();**

You can read WordPress Codex to learn more about this function. And if you able to find out the responsible function, you can use 'wp_deregister_style' to disable that.

Even if you are not able to trace those code, you can override its CSS using the same **wp_add_inline_style** function.

[wp_add_inline_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style)